# Constant error - psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I am getting below error constantly.

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch

The below code is returning 12 rows.

`_rowcount = db_cursor_eb.rowcount`

When I try to run this code.

```
if _rowcount > 0:
    _lResultSet = db_cursor_eb.fetchall()
else:
    _lResultSet = "No record found"
return _lResultSet
```

**Error:**
**line 131, in executequery\n    _row = db_cursor_eb.fetchone()\npsycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch\n"**

Answer (score 0):

It was db_cursor_eb.execute(_query, parameters) instead of db_cursor_eb.executemany(_query, parameters).

Comment: This 'answer' makes no sense, especially as references information that was not in the question. Fix both question and the answer or delete both.